# Angular ModalController to be its own file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was looking at the answer and question outlined in [Angular ui modal with controller in separate js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596809/angular-ui-modal-with-controller-in-separate-js-file) and I wish to achieve the same outcome, that is have the modal controller in its own controller.js file, just that my main controller is implemented in a different way. Here is how I have it.

```
(function () {
     angular.module('app.mainModule')
            .controller('MainController', MainController);

    var ACTION = {
    CANCEL: 0,
    CONFIRM: 1
    };

    MainController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$modal'];
    function MainController($rootScope, $modal) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.method1 = method1;
    vm.method2 = method2;

    function method1(){
       var modalInstance = createModal();
       // do something....
    }

  function createModal(){
        return $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/someModalFile.html',
            controller: 'ModalController as vm',
            resolve: {
                action: function(){
                    return vm.action;
                },
                someVar: function() {
                    return vm.someVar.obj;
                },
                anotherVar: function(){
                    return vm.anotherVar;
                }
            }
        });
    }
 // I want to have this in a separate controller file and 
 // use the MainController to invoke this modal controller.
 function ModalController($modalInstance, someVar, anotherVar){
    var vm = this;

    vm.confirm = confirm;
    vm.cancel = cancel;
    vm.someVar = someVar;   // to display on the modal window
    vm.anotherVar = anotherVar;

    function confirm(){
        $modalInstance.close({action: ACTION.CONFIRM});
    }

    function cancel(){
        $modalInstance.close({action: ACTION.CANCEL});
    }
}
})();
```

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in two easy steps:

**Step1:**

You need to make a new controller file and define the controller for Modal just as you did for MainController as:

**modal-controller.js**

```
(function(){
     //you can get rid of the ModalController you have defined in the same file and rather use this
     angular.module('app.mainModule')
            .controller('ModalController', ModalController);

     ModalController.$inject = ['$modalInstance', 'someVar', AnotherVar];

     function ModalController($modalInstance, someVar, AnotherVar){
          //code here
     };

})();
```

**Step2**:

You need to include this **modal-controller.js** in your **base.html** (or whichever file you are using to include all script files) so that Angular knows that this controller actually exists.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Probably If I understand your question correctly, I think you're looking for this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lH5CMvvIEu8nqihZPfgk?p=preview

Main Controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function(size) {

  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    size: size,
    resolve: {
      items: function() {
        return $scope.items;
      }
    }
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
  }, function() {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function() {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});
```

And Model controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Comment: This is good too. Rahul's answer was more close to what I actually needed. Upvoted your answer since it helped me with some additional info. Thanks.